# 2 or more UIViewcontroller with the same class crash

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I am have multiple view controller in my storyboard with same class called "viewcontroller.swift " and they crash but if I assign operate classes they don't crash how do i fix this?

Comment: viewcontroller.swift is a file,you should use class written in a swift file,not the filename

Comment: Please be more specific to help us give you a better answer. "they crash" tells us so very little. What was the crash, what was the exact error message, what do the relevant parts of the class which crashed look like? Why do you have multiple instances of this controller in your storyboard and what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Jonah i get this error

Comment: @Jonah fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)

Comment: @leo how do i create class inside swift file i am new

Comment: @Leo how do i create class inside swift file i am new

Comment: @systemhola great, so you have an optional somewhere in your app and it has been set to `nil` but then you try to unwrap it (probably by using a `!`) and that isn't possible. Unfortunately we can't read your code from here. Please locate the line on which the app crashes and update your question with the class or method responsible so someone can try to explain how you got into this situation.

Comment: @Nehal i removed everything in thing in viewcontorlller beside the uiview and then i fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)

Comment: @Jonah it happens here textview1.attributedText = attributedString

Comment: @Jonah it happens anywhere where i use an iboutlet for example button.backgroundColor = color132

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer for that is you can not use single `ViewController.swift` for multiple view controllers in your storyboard. Just create a new class for every new view controller in storyboard.

Comment: is there way to use ViewController.swift for multiple view controllers in  storyboard?

Comment: @systemhola no, just create a new UIViewController file for each class

Answer (score 0):

I tried same ViewController sub class in Obj-C for multiple storyboard view controllers and mentioned storyboard id for each ViewController and it worked fine, no crashes occur. You can try this in Swift as well.